# Корректный селектор для элемента

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить данный элемент:

**HTML-элемент в DOM дереве:**

```
<input data-price-id="1681871754" type="text" size="5" value="111" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
```

наверное надо как то так сделать:

```
$("input[ data-price-id = 1681871754 ]");
```

и еще параллельно вопрос, как потом передать в этот селектор вместо значения **1681871754**, например переменную, ну что-то вроде этого:

```
var someVar = 1681871754;
$("input[ data-price-id = someVar ]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $("input[data-price-id='1681871754']");

2) $("input[data-price-id='" + someVar + "']");

Comment: на самом деле у этого **INPUT** есть еще **id="some-id"**, тогда правильно ли будет такой способ? :

    $("input#some-id[ data-price-id = 1681871754 ]");

Comment: да, так тоже будет работать

Comment: @ruslan5t благодарю, все работает :)

Answer (score 2):

Да, до элемента можно добраться таким образом, как вы написали, т.е.

```
$('input[data-price-id="1681871754"]')
```

но это далеко не самый быстрый способ, т.к. поиск элементов input будет вестись по всему дереву DOM, и у каждого элемента будет проверяться этот атрибут. Гораздо эффективнее хотя бы ограничить область поиска каким-то родительским элементом, а еще лучше - прописывать каждому искомому элементу  атрибут id и по этому артибуту вести поиски.

Что касается значения, то для атрибутов типа data-* у jQuery есть метод data():

```
$('input[data-price-id="1681871754"]').data('price-id')
```

Для других случаев можно воспользоваться методом attr:

```
$('input[data-price-id="1681871754"]').attr('data-price-id')
```

Comment: на самом деле у этого **INPUT** есть еще **id="some-id"**, тогда правильно ли будет такой способ? :

    $("input#some-id[ data-price-id = 1681871754 ]");

Comment: т.к. id уникален в пределах DOM, то достаточно просто $('#some-id')

Comment: Либо, если предстоит работать с несколькими однотипными элементами, прописать им один класс и выбирать по классу: $('.some-class')

Comment: @vanchester спасибо за помощь коллега :)

Comment: @Артёмыч, пожалуйста. Отметьте любой из ответов как "верный" (птичка под кнопками-лайками)

Comment: @vanchester @ruslan5t дал ответ и на второй вопрос, не против я ему засчитаю!